# Python: PyPlot Large number of data points

Tags: python, graph, plot, matplotlib

I have three lists each containing cosine values of vectors, and each list has 49,742 data points. I used the flowing basic plotting but entire graph look very cluttered, How can I plot this with less clutter. I would love to draw these with smooth curves, if possible.

Sample of data in each list:

```
pltfColor = [0.837, 0.98, 0.032, 0.755,....,n]
```

Other two list contain similar data and all three lists has n=49742 number of data points

```
plt.plot(pltfColor, 'r.')
plt.plot(pltEdgeColor, 'b.')
plt.plot(pltTexture, 'g.')
plt.ylabel('cosine values')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.show()
```

Here is my  current plot look like
[image]

Comment: I don't understand what the three plot commands are supposed to be plotting - please elaborate.

Comment: @mutzmatron I updated the question with more data.

Comment: Well you can use curves by replacing `'r.'` by `'r-'` for example. But your data looks like it will still be very dense because your x axis has such a large range i.e. you're plotting so many data points.

Comment: If you want to show all the points, the data will be cluttered, not matter what you do. Depending on what you want to show, you can think of creating a density plot, where you make a 2-d grid and color-code the density of points in that grid using `imshow` or `pcolor`.

Answer (score 0):

Given the high density of points, you may be able to pick out clusters by lowering the opacity

```
plt.plot(pltfColor, 'r.', alpha=.1, mec='none')
```

`hexbin` will also make a density plot, as @imsc suggests

Answer (score 0):

I have not your data...

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 50020
x = np.arange(N)
r = np.random.rand(N)

a = 0.07 ; s = 2 ; n = 2

plt.scatter(x[::n], (0.8*np.cos(1.57*r)+0.2*np.cos(r+r+r+x/5000)**2)[::n],
    alpha=a, s=s, label='A')
plt.scatter(x[::n], abs((0.5*np.cos(1.57*r)+0.5*np.cos(r+r+r+x/1000)))[::n],
     alpha=a, s=s, label='B')
plt.scatter(x[::n], (1-(0.8*np.cos(1.57*r)+0.2*np.cos(r+r+r+x/2000)**2)[::n]),
     alpha=a, s=s, label='C')
plt.xlim((0,max(x))) ; plt.ylim((-0.12, 1.0))
for handle in plt.legend(ncol=3).legendHandles:
    handle.set_alpha(0.6)
    handle.set_sizes([72]*N)
```

You can play with `a`, `s` and `n` to get exactly what you want.